# Is GADT extension destroying polymorphism?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, gadt

Is the extension `GADT` in Haskell destroying polymorphism, even in code that don't use GADTs ?

Here's a example which works and don't use GADT

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
--{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

newtype Fix1 f i = In1 { unFix1 :: f (Fix1 f) i }
mcata1 ::      (forall r k. (forall j. r j -> t j) -> f r k -> t k) 
            -> Fix1 f i
            -> t i
mcata1 f (In1 x) = f (mcata1 f) x


newtype Ret i = Ret {unRet :: (i -> Int) -> Int}


-- recusive type
data BushR i = NBR | CBR i (BushR (BushR i))

-- initial algebra
data BushF r i = NB | CB i (r (r i))
type Bush i = Fix1 BushF i

bsumm = mcata1 alg
  where alg :: forall i r. (forall j. r j -> Ret j) -> BushF r i -> Ret i
        alg r NB = Ret (const 0)
        alg r (CB x xs) = Ret (\f -> 
                f x + bsum xs (\ys -> bsum ys f))
                        where
                                bsum  = unRet . r
```

If `GADTs` is enabled we get a compile error

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

newtype Fix1 f i = In1 { unFix1 :: f (Fix1 f) i }
mcata1 ::      (forall r k. (forall j. r j -> t j) -> f r k -> t k) 
            -> Fix1 f i
            -> t i
mcata1 f (In1 x) = f (mcata1 f) x


newtype Ret i = Ret {unRet :: (i -> Int) -> Int}


-- recusive type
data BushR i = NBR | CBR i (BushR (BushR i))

-- initial algebra
data BushF r i = NB | CB i (r (r i))
type Bush i = Fix1 BushF i

bsumm = mcata1 alg
  where alg :: forall i r. (forall j. r j -> Ret j) -> BushF r i -> Ret i
        alg r NB = Ret (const 0)
        alg r (CB x xs) = Ret (\f -> 
                f x + bsum xs (\ys -> bsum ys f)) -- error
                        where
                                bsum  = unRet . r
-- • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: i1 ~ r i1
--   Expected type: r (r i1)
--     Actual type: r i1
-- • In the first argument of ‘bsum’, namely ‘ys’
--   In the expression: bsum ys f
--   In the second argument of ‘bsum’, namely ‘(\ ys -> bsum ys f)’
-- • Relevant bindings include
```

which can be fixed by duplicating bindings

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

newtype Fix1 f i = In1 { unFix1 :: f (Fix1 f) i }
mcata1 ::      (forall r k. (forall j. r j -> t j) -> f r k -> t k) 
            -> Fix1 f i
            -> t i
mcata1 f (In1 x) = f (mcata1 f) x


newtype Ret i = Ret {unRet :: (i -> Int) -> Int}


-- recusive type
data BushR i = NBR | CBR i (BushR (BushR i))

-- initial algebra
data BushF r i = NB | CB i (r (r i))
type Bush i = Fix1 BushF i

bsumm = mcata1 alg
  where alg :: forall i r. (forall j. r j -> Ret j) -> BushF r i -> Ret i
        alg r NB = Ret (const 0)
        alg r (CB x xs) = Ret (\f -> 
                f x + bsum xs (\ys -> bsum2 ys f))
                        where
                                bsum   = unRet . r
                                bsum2  = unRet . r
```

Is there a deep reason for that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling `GADTs` we implicitly also enable [`MonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/let_generalisation.html#extension-MonoLocalBinds) which prevents some forms of `let`- and `where`- type generalizations.

This affects types whose type variables are partly quantified (`i` below), and partly free (`r` below).

```
where bsum :: forall i. r i -> (i -> Int) -> Int
      bsum = unRet . r
```

A simple solution is to provide an explicit type annotation so to force the wanted generalization.

The docs provide a rationale for [`MonoLocalBinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/let_generalisation.html#extension-MonoLocalBinds), showing why it makes sense to restrict generalization in some cases. A [blog post](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/blog/20100930-LetGeneralisationInGhc7.html) from 2010 provides further discussion.

A relevant quote by Simon Peyton-Jones from the blog (slightly reformatted, and using the same links as in the original blog):

> Why did we make it?
>
> It’s a long story, but the short summary is this: I don’t know how to build a reliable, predictable type inference engine for a type system that has both
>
> - (a) generalisation of local let/where and
> - (b) local type equality assumptions, such as those introduced by GADTs.
>
> The story is told in our paper “[Let should not be generalised](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/constraints/index.htm)” and, at greater length, in the journal version “[Modular type inference with local assumptions](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simonpj/Talk:OutsideIn)”.

Comment: To note : adding type signature mentioning `r` requires : 1) `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and 2) an explicit quantification on `forall r.` at some level above

Comment: (and conversely once enabled, we need to quantify locally with `forall i .`  to prevent the local type variable  `i`  to refer to an outside `i` )